# datasource-cfg.properties file is placed in resource folder but still i am getting file not found exception in eclipse neon

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-jdbc

[image: Error page]

I am using:

- Eclipse 4.6 (NEON)
- Spring MVC 4.x
- Spring Security 4.x
- Spring JDBC 4.x
- (Annotation Config)

I am getting the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [datasource-cfg.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I keep it in Java resource folder only but still throwing same exception

[image]